Add round edges to heptagon shaped image with fill in Unity
I am not sure if this is possible I have this image:

This is how it looks when I do radial fill:

My question is if there is a way to make edges rounded while filling the image.
Rough sketch of what I want:


I'm not sure what you mean by "rounded edges". Can you use MS Paint or something to do a mockup of what you're looking for?

I edited the question

I think this would be easier to do with a LineRenderer. You could do it with a shader, but I won't be able to show sample code for that for a day or two at least.

When you are able I would love to see shader solution in the meantime I will try and research line renderer.

Ended up creating this shape with line renderer and used script from this video to help me animate it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMM3BAick4I&ab_channel=HamzaHerbou
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LineAnimator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float animationDuration = 5f;

    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    private Vector3[] linePoints;
    private int pointsCount;

    private void Start()
    {
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        // Store a copy of lineRenderer's points in linePoints array
        pointsCount = lineRenderer.positionCount;
        linePoints = new Vector3[pointsCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++)
        {
            linePoints[i] = lineRenderer.GetPosition(i);
        }

        StartCoroutine(AnimateLine());
    }

    private IEnumerator AnimateLine()
    {
        float segmentDuration = animationDuration / pointsCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < pointsCount - 1; i++)
        {
            float startTime = Time.time;

            Vector3 startPosition = linePoints[i];
            Vector3 endPosition = linePoints[i + 1];

            Vector3 pos = startPosition;
            while (pos != endPosition)
            {
                float t = (Time.time - startTime) / segmentDuration;
                pos = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, t);

                // animate all other points except point at index i
                for (int j = i + 1; j < pointsCount; j++)
                    lineRenderer.SetPosition(j, pos);

                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

Edit:
While this solution kind of works if you just want to fill up line renderer, I notice it cause some problems in my case where line isn't straight when it reaches a new point, so I will be keeping this answer here because it could be helpful to somebody but I won't mark it as accepted.

Shader Solution Outline
I don't think there's any built-in that would do this without writing your own shader-code.
The chain of effects that you want to apply are:

Start with an image where the lines are slightly narrower than you want them to be. (This process will expand the lines slightly)
Radially fill the image so that only a slice of it is visible
Blur the image. This is usually implemented by sampling a few points adjacent to each texel and taking a weighted average of them to get the output value of that texel.
Apply a high/Low filter to the image such that anything above a certain value is set to full white, and anything below that value is set to full black. (Optionally, you can have 3 levels here to create a narrow outline around the bar, too, if that's desired.)

The blur in step 2 will round out the edges but also make the image appear blurry, and the filter in step 3 will remove the blurry appearance while still keeping the rounded appearance.
The way this works is that blurring-then-sharpening causes the image to lose detail without any side effects. Normally, you'd think losing detail is a bad thing, but in this case, the sharp edges are a detail that you would like to lose.
Implementing this in shader code is left as an exercise to the reader (I'm away from my usual tools right now).

I am not really god with sanders so this is way out of my scope, but thanks for the answer if anybody comes along that applies these I would appreciate a code sample :), I am sure that would be a better solution from what I got.
